# PayPal subscription API with ready items and invoices

Tags: php, api, paypal

I have a business account and templates of invoices, as well as items. I searched their docs, but it wasn't quite clear to me whether I can send repeating invoices with an item that has been registered in PayPal.

Instead of requesting a specific sum, I would like to be able to modify just the items on PayPal and that would determine how much one should be charged.

Is this the way this is usually done, or is there a better method to charge customers for monthly subscriptions?

I am trying to implement this using PHP on an e-commerce website.

Answer (score 0):

[PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) use Plans.

Plans are for specific $ amounts at specific times.

If the amount you want to charge is different, or on a different schedule, you *must* create a different Plan to use.

There is no concept of having a library of items that sum up to be the cost of the Plan. If you want to perform such a calculation, you must do so yourself.